# How to calculate Hamming code without converting to binary string?

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, parity, hamming-code

I am trying to solve a problem that comes down to finding the hamming code without using binary string of the long number in java.

I don't understand how we can do that, I have searched at many places like the wikipedia explanation and [this one I found online](https://users.cs.fiu.edu/~downeyt/cop3402/hamming.html) but all of them need binary string to work with, but here in this case I can't use them.

I have a long number that represents the input binary, now I need to find the hamming code.

As I understand it, I can have the empty places at positions 1, 2, 8 ... in that binary. Now I can put 0 or 1 in that place using the boolean that tells me if this is an even parity or odd.

I wrote a code using string and lists, but I need to this without using strings or lists.

```
String text = new Scanner(System.in).next() ;
    int len = text.length() ;
    ArrayList codearray = new ArrayList() ;
    ArrayList pos_arr = new ArrayList() ;


    while (!(len + r + 1 <= Math.pow(2, r))) {
        r++;
    }


    System.out.println("Number of parity bits : "+r);

    for (int i=0 ; i<len + r  ; i++) {

        if (IsPowerTwo(i+1) ){
            codearray.add("?") ;
        }else {
            codearray.add(text.charAt(j));
            j++ ;
        }
    }


    System.out.println(codearray.toString());

    //to determine the position of parity bits
    for (int i=0 ; i< codearray.size() ; i++) {
        if (codearray.get(i) == "?") {
            int k ,s=1;
            // For Debugging.
            //System.out.println("Calculate at position " + (i+1) ) ;
            for (k = i ; k < codearray.size() ; k++){

                if (i==0) {
                    k++ ;
                    pos_arr.add(k);
                }else {

                    pos_arr.add(k+1);
                    if(s % (i+1) == 0) {
                        k += i+1 ;
                    }
                }
                s++ ;

            }

            checkOnes(pos_arr,codearray,i) ;
            pos_arr.clear();
        }


    }

    System.out.println("Code word: ");
    Arr_to_Str(codearray) ;
}

public static boolean IsPowerTwo(int num){
    int checked = num & num -1 ;
    if (checked == 0 ){
        return true ;
    }else {
        return false ;
    }

}
public static void checkOnes(ArrayList array, ArrayList codearray, int position ){

    int count =0;

    for (int i=0 ; i < array.size(); i++) {
        int index = (int) array.get(i) -1 ;
        if (codearray.get(index) == "?"  ) {
            codearray.set(index,0) ;
        }

        int num = Integer.parseInt(codearray.get(index).toString()) ;
        if (num == 1  ) {
            count++ ;
        }
        if(count % 2 ==0 ){
            codearray.set(position, 0) ;
        }else {
            codearray.set(position, 1) ;
        }

    }
}

public static void Arr_to_Str(ArrayList array){
    for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
        System.out.print(array.get(i));
    }
}
```

But this requires me to work with binary string or list, how can I do the same with long numbers like, say 210.

I am really new to bit manipulation and hence I can't wrap my head around this. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you please add some example code?

Comment: Why would you need to work with lists/strings? You can make use of bitwise operations: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm For example `x & ~4` will make the third bit from the right zero.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am new to bit manipulation like this, can you please explain how can I do the same for hamming code.

Comment: @JeremyThen I didn't understand the algorithm to do above without using strings, so I couldn't come up with a code.

Comment: Please show your attempt, any attempt. Check the link, give it a try, then come back if still stuck. We do welcome beginners here, but we expect to see some concrete evidence of real effort in the question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added the code which I was using to do above using strings and lists, but without them I am unable to think so I can't really proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Hamming encoding can be implemented with bit manipulation. It is probably even simpler that with a string. Here are some ideas on the implementation.

Outline of Hamming encoding algorithm is the following

```
input_val is a long int to encode
output_val_is the long int result
for s in 0..5
  count number of bits in input_val whose position has bit s set
  add to output_val the parity of this count
  add next 2^s bits from input_val to output_val
```

There are indeed two problems: getting the parity of a specific set of bits and creating the output with bit shifts.

**Counting set bits on a given pattern***

For Hamming encoding, one must compute parity on a subset of the bit (pattern).
Patterns are 010101010101...01 for first step, 001100110...00110 for second step, etc,  and can be encoded in an array `mask` indexed by the step number.
mask[0]=0x5555555555555555, mask[1]=0x6666666666666666, mask[2]=0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0, mask[3]=0xff00ff00ff00ff00, etc

To get this parity, the simpler is to count the number of bits and to get the lSB of this count.
There is a function in java that gives the number of bits in an integer. Hence the only operation required here is

```
count=Integer.bitcount(input_val & masks[s]) ;
```

where s is the computation stage number.

Then you have to add to output `count & 0x1` to add the parity of the count.

**Adding a bit to an integer**

It is closely related on the number of bits in your input and output value size. I assume for sake on simplicity that both your data can be coded on 64 bits. This means that you have 6 parity bits and that your input data is only part of your variable and that the 6 MSB of input_data are zero.

To add the LSB of an integer `v` to `output_val` the simpler is to add it at the MSB position of result, and to shift it right. After 64 bits are added, all is in its proper place. Note the output_val must be unsigned to avoid a right arithmetic shift.

So, to add the LSB of v to output_val, the operation to do is

```
output_val = (output_val >> 1) | (v<< 63);
```

v<<63 extract the LSB and put it in MSB position. 
The OR adds to the shifted result.

To add several bits (k, for instance), one can use

```
output_val = (output_val >> k) | (v<< (64-k));
```

So the final implementation (to improve) would be something like

```
input_queue = input_val;
output_val = 0;
for (s=0; s<6;s++) {'
  count=Integer.bitcount(input_val & masks[s]) ; // compute parity
  output_val = (output_val >> 1) | (count << 63);// add parity to output
  output_val = (output_val >> (1<<s)) | (input_queue << (64-(1<<s)); 
                                   // add 2^s LSB of input to output
  input_queue >>=(1<<s);           // suppress 2^s bits form input_queue
}
```